# Pass PHP variable to ajax and run PHP function based on that variable

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have Database records which are loop echoes out, so it lists down in Divs each records info.

I'm trying to make a delete button, to delete the specific record from this page view. The loop number tracker variable $i also corresponds to the record ID, so loop 3 outputs a div containing the info of record ID 3.

So I just need to on click pass $i to a PHP function to then run the sql to drop the record with ID $i.

I'd like to do this all on the same page so I'm assuming I need ajax but thats where I get stumped. Also so I can have an alert "Are you sure" I've done ajax with jquery to ajax to php, but never this way.

PHP:

```
                $webserver = 'localhost'; 
                $administrator = 'root';
                $password = '';
                $db_name = 'cdb';
                $db = mysqli_connect($webserver, $administrator, $password, $db_name)
                  or die('Error connecting');

                if( isset($_REQUEST['page'])) 
                {
                  $_SESSION['page'] = $_REQUEST['page'];
                }
                else
                {
                  $_SESSION['page'] = 1;
                }
                $records_per_page = 8;              

                    $query = " SELECT * 
                               FROM cars, users 
                               WHERE cars.dealerID = users.dealerID
                               AND  users.username = '".$_GET['username']."'";          

                $result = mysqli_query($db, $query)
                  or die("Error in query: '$query'");
                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                $i = 1;
                $start = ($_SESSION['page'] - 1) * $records_per_page;
                $end = ($_SESSION['page']) * $records_per_page;
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) and $i < $end) 
                {
                  $i++;
                  if( $i > $start ) 
                  {
                              <div>
                                  delete
                              </div>
                              <div of magic n' fairies>
                                  echo $row['informationandstuff'];
                              </div>
                              }
                            }
```

Delete function:

```
function deleteCar()
{
$delete = "DELETE FROM cars
WHERE carindex = '".$i"'";
}
```

I could post $i to another file and do it bt would prefer to keep to same page and allow for an are you sure js pop up.

Comment: Please share your `form`, `js`, and `php` code relevant to the question as well.

Comment: @vee It'll be messy, 99.9% irrelevant and my initial question covers everything, but ok.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, one way to do this would be to store the $i variable in either an html data attribute, or an id (as you suggested). Then, use jquery to collect that id and pass it to the data property in the ajax call.

Sample list item (I'm assuming a heredoc here):

```
<div class="list-item" data-record-id="{$yourId}">your output</div>
```

Now, collect the id that the user clicked:

```
$('.list-item').click(function(){
    //get item id
    var recordId = $(this).data('record-id');
    deleteRecord(recordId);
});

function deleteRecord(recordId) {
    var recordData = 'recordId=' + recordId;
    var request = $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "the-php-page-you-use-for-async-calls",
        data: recordData,
        success: function(resp){
            //show some validation that the record has been deleted
        }
    });
}
```